# Problemas con Plesk y GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, plesk

¡Buenas! Estoy utilizando GitKraken como software para control de versiones. Tengo un repositorio de GitLab en Plesk, donde tengo una carpeta .ssh con la clave privada y la pública. Se me desconfiguró el GitKraken y ahora ya no puedo subir ni descargar nada de mi servidor, así que he ido a Preferencias y he añadido el archivo id_rsa y el archivo id_rsa.pub que me he descargado del servidor después de volver a apuntar a la dirección ssh de mi servidor, que tiene una dirección con este formato `git@gitlab.com:mi_usuario/direccion/repositorio.git`  pero al intentar realizar la conexión me sale el mensaje

> Fetch failed for 'origin'. Configured SSH key is invalid. Please confirm that is properly associated with your Git provider.

Tras esto he buscado y he encontrado que a las personas que les ocurría este problema, lo solucionaban generando una nueva llave privada y pública desde gitkraken y subiéndolas al servidor, así que lo he hecho, he hecho una copia de seguridad de las antiguas y he subido las nuevas, y nada, me daba el mismo error, de manera que he deshecho los cambios y he vuelto a las antiguas. He probado activar la opción de "usar el agente SSH local" que hay en gitkraken y tras ejecutar `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa` teniendo la clave privada en .ssh, he dado de alta la identidad. Lo he podido comprobar ejecutando `ssh-add -L`, comprobando que la clave pública que me devolvía coincidia con la clave pública del servidor. Pero el error sigue ahí, no puedo hacer nada desde GitKraken. He accedido a mi carpeta desde terminal y he ejecutado `git pull` y me salta este mensaje

> git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
> fatal: No se pudo leer del repositorio remoto.
> Por favor asegúrate que tienes los permisos de acceso correctos
> y que el repositorio existe.

Después de esto ya no sé qué más probar...

Estoy utilizando Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he creado un nuevo repositorio local y lo he enlazado con el repositorio que tenía en el servidor, así he solucionado mi problema.